# Не выводится результат JS-файла

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, я недавно решил создать простой чат на js, py. Некоторые непонятные моменты решаю с помощью Ютуба и стака. Наткнулся на одного автора. Решил попробовать его способ, но мой JS-файл (идентичен его файлу) отказывается работать. У него он работает корректно, у меня нет. Для проверки я в консоль попытался вывести "123" - результата ноль. Такое ощущение, что он не подключен (хотя я его подключил правильно). Ошибок никаких нет. Помогите плз. Вот тестовый код js-файла:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    console.log(123);


}, false);
```

Вот html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Version1</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="messages_container" style="border: 2px solid"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="message_input">
        <input type="button" name="send_message_button" value="Send message">
    </div>

    
    <script type="application/javascript" scr = "websocket_client.js"></script>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в теге

```
<script type="application/javascript" scr = "websocket_client.js"></script>
```

Не **scr**, а **src**

Comment: Боже, как я это не заметил. Спасибо огромное!